# Reporting effect size for permutational ANOVA

Tags: anova, permutation-test

I ran a permutational one-way ANOVA with blocking. I would like to report the permuted p-values along with an effect size (difference in means). However, the permutational ANOVA does not allow one to get these estimates, say using emmeans. Given this, is it valid to report the mean difference with confidence intervals from a parametric ANOVA and report the p-values from the permutational ANOVA?

Comment: If you used permutational ANOVA (with blocking), you must have had a reason to not use parametric ANOVA. That is, you would probably not trust the outcomes of parametric ANOVA, anyway, and you would deem the confidence intervals invalid.